# CADObjectGetRelatedObjects failed with error Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=268435459 "

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I've download the Apple's official example code SimpleEKDemo, this is a calendar relation project.

I run it with iphone, and when i create a event and edite it, add a notes .in the end, i delete it ,at this time. Below is the console log error:
 `SimpleEKDemo[1335:907] CADObjectGetRelatedObjects failed with error Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=268435459 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error 268435459 - (ipc/send) invalid destination port)"`

[image: Screenshot]

I have another question: No matter how I operate it, the function `- (EKCalendar *)eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendarForNewEvents:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller` not be called. why? when the function will be called、

Comment: Showing the code would help figure out the problem.

Comment: you can down load these code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160. thank you